# Does Opentok iOS SDK support Archiving?

Tags: ios, xcode6, opentok, archiving

While playing with the OpenTok SDK, I figured it out that it doesn't provide archiving support for iOS. Is that so or I am having a wrong conclusion? I need to record both video and audio of the session's subscriber.

Regards

Comment: You'll need to provide more information for us to be able to answer this question correctly (1) What version of the OpenTok mobile SDKs are you using? (2) What version of the server-side SDKs are you using? (3) Have you read this tutorial, and found it to be unclear https://tokbox.com/opentok/tutorials/archiving/ ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using iOS SDK v2.2 and up, then you should be able to get archiving capabilities. Archiving is started, stopped, and managed by your server so you would have to get control your archive from your server using our [server side sdks](https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/server/).

Here's the [tutorial](https://tokbox.com/opentok/tutorials/archiving/) for archiving.

If you want to test out archiving, you can visit [opentokrtc](https://opentokrtc.com) on your browser, join the same room on the [opentokrtc iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/opentokrtc/id715248169?mt=8), and start an archive.